# generate a spesific data by date in web2py

Tags: python, date, web2py

im stuck about my application.
i want to generate spesific data from database by date i want to chosse.

here my models:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# on_define_lion
def on_define_lion(table):
    # represent
    table.time_taken.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.ukuran_lebar_toko.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.weeks.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.mama_lemon_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.zinc_refreashing_cool_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.zinc_black_shine_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.systema_spring_fresh_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.systema_mentol_breeze_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.emeron_anti_dandruff_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.emeron_black_shine_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.ciptadent_maxi_12_penjualan.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.mama_lemon_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.zinc_refreashing_cool_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.zinc_black_shine_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.systema_spring_fresh_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.systema_mentol_breeze_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.emeron_anti_dandruff_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.emeron_black_shine_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.ciptadent_maxi_12_stock.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.total_transaksi_dalam_satuan_rupiah.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_integer
    table.foto_outlet.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_url
    table.foto_bukti_trasnsaksi.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_url
    table.foto_display_produk_1.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_url
    table.foto_produk_dislay_2.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_url
    table.foto_posm_1.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_url
    table.foto_posm_2.represent = ads_field_constructor.represent_url
    # requires
    table.auditor.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()
    table.date_of_response.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_date()
    table.sync_date.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_date()
    table.time_of_response.requires = IS_TIME()
    table.sync_time.requires = IS_TIME()
    table.jenis_kunjungan.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_register_outlet)
    table.berada_di_dalam_pasar_atau_tidak.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_pasar)
    table.type_outlet.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_type_outlet)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_sembako.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_food.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_beverage.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_ice_cream.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_personal_care.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_household.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_cigarette.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_medicine.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_vitamin.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_baby_care.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_chiller.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_coolbox.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_freezer_ice_cream.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_rak_rokok_special.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_special_branding.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_program_display.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_yes)
    table.di_kunjungi_salesman_principle_terkait_program_ads.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_ya)
    table.apakah_outlet_melakukan_transaksi.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_beli)
    table.alasan_tidak_mau_beli.requires = ads_field_constructor.requires_set_not_empty(list_alasan_tidak_beli)

# create table : lion
db.define_table('lion', 
    Field('uuid'), 
    Field('auditor'), 
    Field('date_of_response', 'date'), 
    Field('time_of_response', 'time'), 
    Field('sync_date', 'date'), 
    Field('sync_time', 'time'), 
    Field('geo_location'), 
    Field('time_taken', 'integer'), 
    Field('jenis_kunjungan'), 
    Field('data_toko'), 
    Field('id_outlet'), 
    Field('nama_outlet'), 
    Field('area'), 
    Field('tag_location'), 
    Field('alamat'), 
    Field('kecamatan'), 
    Field('patokan'), 
    Field('berada_di_dalam_pasar_atau_tidak'), 
    Field('type_outlet'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_sembako'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_food'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_beverage'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_ice_cream'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_personal_care'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_household'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_cigarette'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_medicine'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_vitamin'), 
    Field('katagori_produk_yang_di_jual_baby_care'), 
    Field('kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_chiller'), 
    Field('kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_coolbox'), 
    Field('kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_freezer_ice_cream'), 
    Field('kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_rak_rokok_special'), 
    Field('kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_special_branding'), 
    Field('kondisi_yang_ada_di_toko_program_display'), 
    Field('ukuran_lebar_toko', 'integer'), 
    Field('di_kunjungi_salesman_principle_terkait_program_ads'), 
    Field('nama_perusahaan_salesman_tersebut'), 
    Field('alasan_besedia_beli_di_motoris_adshouse'), 
    Field('foto_outlet'), 
    Field('data_transaksi'), 
    Field('weeks', 'integer'), 
    Field('apakah_outlet_melakukan_transaksi'), 
    Field('alasan_tidak_mau_beli'), 
    Field('mama_lemon_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('zinc_refreashing_cool_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('zinc_black_shine_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('systema_spring_fresh_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('systema_mentol_breeze_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('emeron_anti_dandruff_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('emeron_black_shine_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('ciptadent_maxi_12_penjualan', 'integer'), 
    Field('mama_lemon_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('zinc_refreashing_cool_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('zinc_black_shine_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('systema_spring_fresh_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('systema_mentol_breeze_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('emeron_anti_dandruff_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('emeron_black_shine_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('ciptadent_maxi_12_stock', 'integer'), 
    Field('total_transaksi_dalam_satuan_rupiah', 'integer'), 
    Field('foto_bukti_trasnsaksi'), 
    Field('foto_display_produk_1'), 
    Field('foto_produk_dislay_2'), 
    Field('foto_posm_1'), 
    Field('foto_posm_2'), 
    #auth.signature,
    on_define = on_define_lion, 
    format = '%(uuid)s')
```

here my modules:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from gluon import *

# represent
represent_integer = lambda value, field: \
    SPAN('%s' % (format(value, ",d").replace(",", ".") ), 
         _class = 'text-success') if value > 0 else SPAN(0, _class = 'text-danger')
represent_url = lambda value, field: A('View', _target="_blank", _href="%s" % value) if value else ''

# requires
requires_date = lambda: \
    IS_DATE(format = current.T('%Y-%m-%d'), error_message = current.T('Enter date as yyyy-mm-dd') )

requires_set_not_empty = lambda list_value: IS_IN_SET(list_value, zero = current.T('Choose One') )

# widget
widget_string = lambda field, value: \
    SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget(field, value, 
                                  _class = "form-control string", 
                                  _placeholder = current.T('Should be filled') )
```

i want to create a controller like this:

choose date

start date: _________

end date:__________

submit(button)

so after i press the submit button i want a table to view database between date start and date end. help me in totaly stuck, thankyou

------U P D A T E D------

Im using this code in my controller,

```
 def non_register(): 
    form = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field("start_date", type="date"),
    Field("end_date", type="date"))
    if form.process().accepted:
        q = ((db.lion.date_of_response >= form.vars.start_date) &
             (db.lion.date_of_response <= form.vars.end_date))
    rows = db(q).select()
    return dict(form=form,rows=rows)
```

but it show an error

```
<type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'> local variable 'q' referenced before assignment
```

and then how to show the rows from this form? will be apreciate about the answer, thankyou

Comment: Your model looks like one or the other field should be a reference instead.

Comment: so i must define another table to dummy the result in my form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SQLFORM.factory`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-factory) to create the desired form.

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field("start_date", type="date"),
    Field("end_date", type="date"))
```

This will generate nice date pickers, and both `form.vars.start_date` and `form.vars.end_date` will be `datetime.date` instances that you can directly include in your DAL query.

```
q = ((db.yourtable.date >= form.vars.start_date) &
     (db.yourtable.date <= form.vars.end_date))
rows = db(q).select()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @alexaxeel You're putting the query in the wrong place. It should be like `db(query).select(...)`, as in my example.

Comment: it show the another error, could you check my updated question? did i write it wrong?

Comment: @alexaxeel Please follow my example. You're calling `db()` with no query, it should be `db(q).select()` where `q` is exactly what I put in the example.

Comment: already do your code sir, thankyou before. but if i implement ur code i got error like this "<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'Field' object has no attribute 'date'" , i write this (db.lion.date_of_response.date >= form.vars.start_date) . db.lion.date_of_response field have data like this 2017-02-28, so where the error came from? thank you

Comment: The trailing ".date" is wrong, it should be: `db.lion.date_of_response >= form.vars.start_date`.

Comment: oke got it, but it still get some error. your code i update in my stackoverflow question, after form i write if form.process().accepted: and this error showed up <type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'> local variable 'q' referenced before assignment
did u know whats the problem is? @cdonts

Comment: @alexaxeel The `rows = db(q).select()` statement should go inside the `if form...` too.

Comment: yup already put it inside, still got the error "<type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'> local variable 'rows' referenced before assignment"

Comment: @alexaxeel Just add `rows = None` before the if. However I think you should definitely take a Python book before moving on...